# I got "Your device is corrupt. It can't be trusted and may not work properly" on a brand new Nexus 5X. What should I do?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5

Through Project Fi of Google, I ordered and got a brand new Nexus 5X with Android 6.0 on it.  The first time it powered up, it said

```
Your device is corrupt. It can't be trusted and may not work properly.
```

Although I can still use the phone, every time I restart or turn on the phone, the above message will show for a few seconds.

What can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Unlocked bootloader = yellow triangle warning; modified system/kernel = red triangle warning.

As long as the device functions fine you shouldn't worry much; however if restoring is what you need, then flash a [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) then relock bootloader. Do turn on "OEM unlocking" in Developer options after that, so that you have a chance to recover in case anything happens.

Comment: after spending close to an hour with the customer service and wiping every thing out, the same corrupt message still showed every time. But, it asked me to install "updates", which upgraded without me knowing to Android 7.0, and the corrupt message went away after that. Now I have to spend time reinstall all the apps and configure everything. If they had told me upgrading to Android 7.0 would make the message go away, then I might do it without wiping out the phone's data. But then, shipping a brand new phone to customers with a corrupt message... what in the world is that